# Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex to Numpy Matrix

Tags: numpy, pandas, matrix

I have a pandas DataFrame with 2 indexes. (MultiIndex) I want to get out a Numpy  Matrix with something like `df.as_matrix(...)` but this matrix has shape `(n_rows, 1)`. I want a matrix of shape `(n_index1_rows, n_index2_rows, 1)`.

Is there a way to use `.groupby(...)` then a `.values.tolist()` or `.as_matrix(...)` to get the desired shape?

**EDIT**: Data

```
                                                              value  
current_date                  temp_date                                        
1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237485 1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237489   30.497100   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237494    9.584300   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237455   10.134200   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237494    7.803683   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237400   10.678700   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237373    9.700000   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237180   15.000000   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446236961   12.928866   
                              1970-01-01 00:00:01.446237032   10.458800
```

This is kind of the idea:

```
np.array([np.resize(x.as_matrix(["value"]).copy(), (500, 1)) for (i, x) in df.reset_index("current_date").groupby("current_date")])
```

Comment: You want a 3D array? Or just a 2D array including the index as well as the column?

Comment: 3D array. All values in np.array should be column values (not indexes)

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data with desired output?

Comment: Done. Ignore the funky datetimes

Comment: Sorry, why is this meant to become a 3D array?  You have two indices (i=current_date and j=temp_date, presumably with some mapping -- right now temp_date isn't sorted, so it's not clear) and the value those indices specify.  Isn't that a 2D object?

Comment: It is a 2D object and Im trying to get out a 3d one thats resized to the appropriate size. Essentially the idea is that for every `current_date`, I get 500 `values` with index `temp_date`. Check the little code snippet. I was just wanting a better way to do it. Another option would be to resize `temp_date` so that for every `current_date`, there are 500 `temp_dates`

Comment: `xray` (Continuum has been pushing it pretty hard lately) was written for this purpose and will accept a DataFrame as a constructor. How important is it that the result is a `numpy` matrix? See: http://xray.readthedocs.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 11):

I think what you want is to unstack the multiindex, e.g.

```
df.unstack().values[:, :, np.newaxis]
```

Edit: if you have duplicate indices, unstacking won't work, and you probably want a `pivot_table` instead:

```
pivoted = df.reset_index().pivot_table(index='current_date',
                                       columns='temp_date',
                                       aggfunc='mean')
arr = pivoted.values[:, :, np.newaxis]
arr.shape
# (10, 50, 1)
```

Here's a full example of `unstack`. First we'll create some data:

```
current = pd.date_range('2015', periods=10, freq='D')
temp = pd.date_range('2015', periods=50, freq='D')
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([current, temp],
                                 names=['current_date', 'temp_date'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'val':np.random.rand(len(ind))},
                  index=ind)
df.head()
#                               val
# current_date temp_date           
# 2015-01-01   2015-01-01  0.309488
#              2015-01-02  0.697876
#              2015-01-03  0.621318
#              2015-01-04  0.308298
#              2015-01-05  0.936828
```

Now we unstack the multiindex: we'll show the first 4x4 slice of the data:

```
df.unstack().iloc[:4, :4]
#                     val                                 
# temp_date    2015-01-01 2015-01-02 2015-01-03 2015-01-04
# current_date                                            
# 2015-01-01     0.309488   0.697876   0.621318   0.308298
# 2015-01-02     0.323530   0.751486   0.507087   0.995565
# 2015-01-03     0.805709   0.101129   0.358664   0.501209
# 2015-01-04     0.360644   0.941200   0.727570   0.884314
```

Now extract the numpy array, and reshape to [nrows x ncols x 1] as you specified in the question:

```
vals = df.unstack().values[:, :, np.newaxis]
print(vals.shape)
# (10, 50, 1)
```

Comment: I get `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape` when trying to unstack. I have a ton of rows with some having the same `temp_date` (but different values). Id have to unstack millions of indexes. Is there a way to avoid this? Reindex the `temp_date` or something like this?

Comment: Oh – didn't know you had duplicates. In that case, you need to do some sort of aggregation to get the result you want (and you'll have to decide which aggregation is appropriate for your data) A pivot table would be a good approach: see my edit above.